# React not render checked attribute

Tags: reactjs

Currently i am using Jest to test my React App. And i have the following code:

```
var component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<input type="radio" defaultChecked={true}/>)
var node =  ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component)

console.log(node.outerHTML)
// Return
// <input data-reactroot="" type="radio">
```

Why checked attribute is not rendering?

Comment: http://www.webpackbin.com/E1jvGHB_W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i update my react it works. But in the tests the outerHTML don't shows the checked attribute like Vijay says. So, use the follow expect:

```
expect(node.checked).toEqual(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The checked attribute may not be there in the outerHTML. But the test for node.checked returns true.

```
import React from 'react';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

describe('radio_test', () => {
  it('outputs default', () => {
    const component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<input type="radio" defaultChecked={true}/>);
    const node =  ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component);
    expect(node.type).toEqual('radio');
    expect(node.checked).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.